# Background color and console text color

Tags: windows, powershell

I am using PowerShell and I have run into the issue that I cannot distinguish certain colored text from the background. I have tried to go with default PowerShell blue, black, white, grey... There is a problem with all colors. For example with white - vagrant is colored yellow. If I choose black or blue then I cannot see Laravel's artisan which is blue (inside vagrant box). On grey I think I didn't read yellow and the bring green from logging into vagrant.

It's not as if I can change the background on the go as it often retains the background color as text background color. Also switching constantly would be annoying. I have tried Googling said issue but I have not come across anything that corresponds to the issue I am having. Surely there is a solution for this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this as a separate post since the only response I got was missing a few details to make it complete.

If you ever run across this error, then you indeed go to `Properties > Colors` and not only change the background color but **change all the other colors presets to match**. They are not there to offer you some presets to choose from, which I mistakenly believed - they are actual color definitions used by the console. When you are done, make sure that the selected colors for background, text etc have not shifted.

For example: PowerShell is dark blue. As such you cannot use colors that are similar and the bright regular blue I will change to light blue, which stands out easily. And voilá.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the text color for specific syntax in the colors tab. In the properties tab when you right click on power shell. Go to colors tab and edit it according

Comment: See this part of my question "It's not as if I can change the background on the go as it often retains the background color as text background color. Also switching constantly would be annoying. " Meaning I know about this and this is not the solution I am looking for. It does not solve my problem.